# Category SubCategory

Tags: flutter

I have category and subcategory for my user points.
and I want showing points with category and subcategory.
how I must do?

Example

Category-1
SubCategory-1 Point-1 Point-2 Point-3 Point-4
SubCategory-2 Point-1 Point-2 Point-3 Point-4

Category-2
SubCategory-1 Point-1 Point-2 Point-3 Point-4
SubCategory-2 Point-1 Point-2 Point-3 Point-4

Category-3
SubCategory-1 Point-1 Point-2 Point-3 Point-4
SubCategory-2 Point-1 Point-2 Point-3 Point-4

Comment: can you please elaborate on your question and also please share some code snippet for better understanding

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use ListView Widget or GridView Widget to show the list category with the points....

Comment: I writing categories with listviews.
But i dont know how can write subcategories and releated points.

Comment: you have to write nested ListView... what's my idea is you can write ListView category in vertical scroll and inside each row you have to put subcategory as another listview with horizontal scroll...

Comment: how I call function in listview for category's ID.
So I can query by category ID and write subcategory and points.